# How to access image in Xamarin.Forms using HTML?

Tags: html, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to access an image in Xamarin.Forms using the HTML code below. The text inside the DIV tag is shown in the emulator but the image is not appearing.

```
var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();

htmlSource.Html = @"<html>
<head>
    <link rel=""stylesheet"" href=""style.css"">
</head>
<body>
    <img img src='world_bank.png'/>
    <div>Helloooo</div>
    </body>
</html>";

webVieew.Source = htmlSource;
```

Comment: `<img img src='world_bank.png'/>` you have a double `img` element in your tag

Comment: To add to @SushiHangover 's comment, your `src` attribute is using single quotes which is invalid html. That also needs to be double quotes the same way you have it in your stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks , it worked with double quotes but the image needs to be inside the Droid --> asset folder then only its working.